# Converting Vector into Dates in R

Tags: r, date, vector

I have a vector of dates of the form BW01.68, BW02.68, ... , BW26.10. BW stands for "bi-week", so for example, "BW01.68" represents the first bi-week of the year 1968, and "BW26.10" represents the 26th (and final) bi-week of the year 2010. Using R, how could I convert this vector into actual dates, say, of the form 01-01-1968, 01-15-1968, ... , 12-16-2010? Is there a way for R to know exactly which dates correspond to each bi-week? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does your dating respect day of week? Should all the values returned be a Monday (or some other day), or can they be any date in those two weeks?

Comment: I don't believe it matters what day of the week it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution.

```
biwks <- c("BW01.68", "BW02.68", "BW26.10")

bw <- substr(biwks,3,4)
yr <- substr(biwks,6,7)
yr <- paste0(ifelse(as.numeric(yr) > 15,"19","20"),yr)

# the %j in the date format is the number of days into the year
as.Date(paste(((as.numeric(bw)-1) * 14) + 1,yr,sep="-"),format="%j-%Y")

#[1] "1968-01-01" "1968-01-15" "2010-12-17"
```

Though I will note that a 'bi-week' seems a strange measure and I can't be sure that just using 14 day blocks is what is intended in your work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this code a lot shorter. I have spaced out each step to help understanding but you could finish it off in one (long) line of code.

```
bw <- c('BW01.68', 'BW02.68','BW26.10','BW22.13')

# the gsub will ensure that bw01.1 the same as bw01.01, bw1.01, or bw1.1

#isolating year no
yearno <- as.numeric(
  gsub(
    x = bw,
    pattern = "BW.*\\.",
    replacement = ""
    )
)

#isolating and converting bw to no of days
dayno <- 14 * as.numeric(
  gsub(
    x = bw,
    pattern = "BW|\\.[[:digit:]]{1,2}",
    replacement = ""
  )
)

#cutoff year chosen as 15
yearno <- yearno + 1900
yearno[yearno < 1915] <- yearno[yearno < 1915] + 100


# identifying dates
dates <- as.Date(paste0('01/01/',yearno),"%d/%m/%Y") + dayno
# specifically identifinyg mondays of that week no
mondaydates <- dates - as.numeric(strftime(dates,'%w')) + 1
```

Output -

```
> bw
[1] "BW01.68" "BW02.68" "BW26.10" "BW22.13"
> dates
[1] "1968-01-15" "1968-01-29" "2010-12-31" "2013-11-05"
> mondaydates
[1] "1968-01-15" "1968-01-29" "2010-12-27" "2013-11-04"
```

PS: Just be careful that you're aligned with how bw is measured in your data and whether you're translating it correctly. You should be able to manipulate this to get it to work, for instance you might encounter a bw 27.